# Function to apply arbitrary functions in R

Tags: r

How would one implement in R the function `apply.func(func, arg.list)`, which takes an arbitrary function `func` and a suitable list `arg.list` as arguments, and returns the result of calling `func` with the arguments contained in `arg.list`.  E.g.

```
apply.func(foo, list(x="A", y=1, z=TRUE))
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(x="A", y=1, z=TRUE)
```

Thanks!

P.S. FWIW, the Python equivalent of `apply.func` would be something like

```
def apply_func(func, arg_list):
    return func(*arg_list)
```

or

```
def apply_func(func, kwarg_dict):
    return func(**kwarg_dict)
```

or some variant thereof.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `do.call` is what you're looking for. You can read about it via `?do.call`.

The classic example of how folks use `do.call` is to `rbind` data frames or matrices together:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = letters[1:5])
d2 <- data.frame(x = 6:10,y = letters[6:10])

do.call(rbind,list(d1,d2))
```

Here's another fairly trivial example using `sum`:

```
do.call(sum,list(1:5,runif(10)))
```

Answer (score 7):

R allows functions to be passed as arguments to functions.  This means you can define `apply.func` as follows (where `f` is a function and `...` indicates all other parameters:

```
apply.func <- function(f, ...)f(...)
```

You can then use `apply.func` to and specify any function where the parameters makes sense:

```
apply.func(paste, 1, 2, 3)
[1] "1 2 3"

apply.func(sum, 1, 2, 3)
[1] 6
```

However, note that the following may not produce the results you expected, since `mean` takes a vector as an argument:

```
apply.func(mean, 1, 2, 3)
[1] 1
```

Note that there is also a base R function called `do.call` which effectively does the same thing.

Comment: `f <- match.fun(f)` will be sanity check if function argument is exist function.