# How to use a 'list' object when a '...' argument is required?

Tags: r, list, arguments, ellipsis, variadic-functions

In many R functions the `...` argument is used to supply several objects. How can I supply a `list` object in a `...` argument?

For example:

```
x1 <- head(iris)
x2 <- tail(iris)
rbind(x1, x2)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
#4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
#6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    setosa
#145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
#146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
#147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
#148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
#149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
#150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

But assume that I have the `x1` and `x2` data frames in a `list`. How can I use that `list` with the `...` argument in `rbind`?

I've already tried the following, with no success:

```
rbind(list(x1, x2))
rbind(substitute(list(x1, x2))[-1])
rbind(unlist(list(x1, x2)))
```

In each of these cases the result is NOT as that from `rbind(x1, x2)`. What am I missing?

**UPDATE1**:
As suggested in the answers, `do.call(rbind, list(x1, x2))` seems to work perfectly in this case. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid `do.call` machinery. In other words, is it possible to convert `list(x1, x2)` so that `...` understands it correctly?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192138/324364

Comment: `do.call` is a fabulous function, and I am sure you have hurt its feelings when you say you want to avoid it for no good reason. I also don't understand why you think `rbind(list)` would work. As you say, `rbind` takes several objects in `...`. a list is a single object.

Comment: @rawr No offense was intended. :) As for `list`, it is a collection of several objects. I was hoping that a trick similar to `unlist(list)` would automagically pass the several embedded objects to `rbind()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do.call` is what you use in this case.

```
df1 <- head(iris)
df2 <- tail(iris)
l <- list(df1, df2)

do.call(rbind, l)
##     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
## 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
## 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
## 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
## 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
## 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
## 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    setosa
## 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
## 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
## 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
## 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
## 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
## 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I was wondering if it's possible to avoid `do.call` machinery?

Comment: @landroni Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: For no good, reason, I guess. I was wondering if this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

`plyr` has a function that turns other functions to a form that accepts lists as arguments.  It's basically just a wrapper to `do.call`, but if this is something you do a lot you could define your own custom functions:

```
library(plyr)
rbindl <- splat(rbind)
lst <- list(head(iris, 3), tail(iris, 3))
rbindl(lst)
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
# 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
# 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
# 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```